# Design for relation database with object structure

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am designing database for my app. I am using PostgreSQL. It has to be generic app and real world structure looks like this:

**Category** (e.g. vegetation) ---> **Phenomenon** (e.g. tree) ---> **Parameters** (e.g. type - coniferous vs. deciduous, height in meters - 10 and so on)

The database can store a lot of categories, phenomenons, parameters and their values. One category can have N phenomenons, one phenomenon can have N parameters.

So I created these tables:

```
Category
--------
id
name


Phenomenon
----------
id
name
category FK (to Category)


Parameter
---------
phenomenon FK (to Phenomenon)
name
value <-- here is a problem
```

In value column can be value from dictionary, varchar value, numeric value or boolean value. How can I design **Parameter** table? Should I make more columns for different types of value (varchar - can be dictionary value without integrity check, numeric, boolean). Or is there any design considering this problem? I don't want use JSON or XML.

I am really appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Parameter` table is an EAV (entity-attribute-value) table and is not supported by the relational model. The RM is a first-order logical model which requires that every attribute have a single domain.

In your model, the domain of the `value` attribute depends on the value of the `name` attribute. So, it's not relational but it is implementable in SQL databases, though it's a pattern I avoid when possible since it makes integrity constraints difficult to impossible and complicates queries.

In first-order models, each distinct parameter would be in a separate relation, e.g.:

```
PhenomenonHeight
----------------
phenomenon FK (to Phenomenon)
height

PhenomenonType
----------------
phenomenon FK (to Phenomenon)
type
```

and so on.

Comment: Thx for the answer. But I am not sure about the example. It is separate table for every parameter? What if I will need to add new phenomenon and new parameters? I found some solutions on EAV (I wasn't able to name the problem right). In this presentation on slide 16, they have model with different column. Is this the same thing as you provide?

Comment: Also found this: https://inviqa.com/blog/eav-data-model Looks very similar

Comment: In a relational model, you can add new phenomena and new categories without changing the schema, but you would have to add a new table for each new parameter. Such are the limitations of a first-order model.